# Active directory scheduled job distribution + copy files to remote server

Tags: scheduled-tasks, active-directory

Just I was wondering if it's possible to schedule a job and distribute to all clients on the domain. What we want to do is basically to run that job on clients to copy files from their PCs to a remote server every night. There are ways of opening a FTP client on the client PCs but that involves visual operation of the FTP client which we don't want to have.

The network structure is similar to this: 
our network -> administration -> clients (connected through VPN)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create on all domain clients PC scheduled task using [Group Policy Preference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx)

But in order to be able to copy files to a network share is required run a task on behalf of a domain user who has write access to this resource.

Copying can be performed, for example, [xcopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll check and get back to you.